# Python Crash Course - Alien Invasion - increase_speed() doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing Alien invasion. At the chapter Leveling up, i've an issue with the method increase_speed(). It does nothing, so the game won't go faster after a new wave of aliens arrives.

Here is my code in settings.py:

```
def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):

    self.velocity = 2.0
    self.projectile_speed = 3.0
    self.alien_speed = 1.0
    # 1 = droite, -1 = gauche
    self.fleet_direction = 1

def increase_speed(self):
    self.velocity *= self.speed_scale
    self.alien_speed *= self.speed_scale
    self.projectile_speed *= self.speed_scale
```

And in main.py

```
    def check_collisions_bullet_alien(self):
    # Gestion des collisions entre le groupe projectiles et le groupe aliens, résultant du kill des deux entités
    collision = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.projectiles_gp, self.alien.aliens_gp, True, True)
    if collision :
        self.stats.score += self.settings.alien_points
    if not self.alien.aliens_gp:
        self.projectiles_gp.empty()
        self.alien.create_fleet()
        self.settings.increase_speed()
        self.stats.score += self.settings.all_aliens_points
```

I've checked for the source code of the game on the web but I don't understand where I've made a mistake.

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Where is `self.speed_scale` defined? Can you add a link to the crash course, or rather to the exercise you are doing?

Comment: Is `self.speed_scale == 1`? That would explain everything

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have an issue with code that you have copied and pasted from a book or other resource, you should *ask the author* about it. Stack Overflow is for questions about your own code - because with your own code, you understand it (and the thought process behind it) well enough to explain in detail. With someone else's code, reported by a third party, we can't understand *what is supposed to happen* when the code runs.

Comment: self.speed_scale is defined in settings.py just before the sample of code i've posted. It's equal to 3.

Comment: (con't.) When you post your own code, normally you would try to [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), [find](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [isolate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem yourself first, but it's difficult to do those things if you aren't the original designer of the code. To start the "understand" step, re-read the chapter. See how `increase_speed` is explained, and where `self.speed_scale` is supposed to come from, and how `self.velocity` etc. should be used.

Comment: Here's what the `_check_bullet_alien_collisions()` method looks like in the [book's code](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_14/leveling_up/alien_invasion.py#L122). You seem to be following a different naming convention, so it's hard to make a direct comparison. Is this your actual indentation? Your if blocks are not indented under your method definition. Also, you're checking whether `self.alien.aliens_gp` evaluates to True, and the book code checks whether the group `self.aliens` evaluates to True. What is `self.alien.aliens_gp`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved : I was trying to change a static variable throught an instance of the Settings class. So, Python was creating a dynamic variable instead of changing the static one.

Solution : Call directly the static variable of the Class to change it in the increase_speed() fonction.